# Gradient mask not showing

Tags: swift, quartz-core

I am trying to draw a gradient, fading in opacity.

I see no effect from drawing. Tried changing the colors. The frames look right. Why isn't this opacity fade showing up?

```
func createGradient() {
        let h = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
        let y = collectionView.frame.origin.y + (cellSize() * 3)
        let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: h - y))

        let l = CAGradientLayer()
        l.frame = v.bounds
        l.colors = [UIColor.greenColor().CGColor, UIColor.blueColor().CGColor]

        l.startPoint = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0.5), y: CGFloat(0.0));
        l.endPoint = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0.5), y: CGFloat(1.0));
        v.layer.mask = l;
        view.addSubview(v)
    }
```

My logs:

```
(lldb) po l
<CAGradientLayer:0x618000228b00; position = CGPoint (207 101); bounds = CGRect (0 0; 414 202); allowsGroupOpacity = YES; colors = (
    "<CGColor 0x6180000b2c00> [<CGColorSpace 0x6100000376c0> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; sRGB IEC61966-2.1; extended range)] ( 0 1 0 1 )",
    "<CGColor 0x6180000b2c60> [<CGColorSpace 0x6100000376c0> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; sRGB IEC61966-2.1; extended range)] ( 0 0 1 1 )"
)>

(lldb) po v
<UIView: 0x7fe1b3d1d3b0; frame = (0 534; 414 202); layer = <CALayer: 0x618000228880>>

(lldb)
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `v.layer.mask = l` with `v.layer.addSublayer(l)`

```
func createGradient() {
        let h = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
        let y = collectionView.frame.origin.y + (cellSize() * 3)
        let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: h - y))

        let l = CAGradientLayer()
        l.frame = v.bounds
        l.colors = [UIColor.greenColor().CGColor, UIColor.blueColor().CGColor]

        l.startPoint = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0.5), y: CGFloat(0.0));
        l.endPoint = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0.5), y: CGFloat(1.0));
        v.layer.addSublayer(l)
        view.addSubview(v)
    }
```